# Django internationalization problems

Tags: django, internationalization

I have template with the following:

```
{% load i18n %}
  {% trans "Welcome to my site!" %}
```

I use RequestContext, have called makemessages, edited .po files and compiled messages, but everything is not translated, I just see the same message even when I load the page.

Extract from .po file

```
msgid "Welcome to my site!"

msgstr "blahblah"
```

Comment: Maybe you have more than one language defined

Comment: Yes, I have two and I have called makemessages for both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get translations to show in templates:

Your `settings.py` should have the following:

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True # optional, but recommended
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us' # Or whatever language you want as default
```

You should have `'django.core.context_processors.i18n'` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

You should add `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'` in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` (after `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'`)

Make sure your templates have `{% load i18n %}` somewhere near the top.

Once you have translated and compiled the messages, to actually get the translation to show, you need to tell django which language you need. To do that, do one of the following:

1. Set `django_language` key in the session which the language code you want.
2. Set a cookie called `django_language` to the language you want.

If after all the above, you are not getting any translations to show - then django is not able to find your message files.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was the order of middleware classes.